# how to set image as button in xml and in class

Tags: android, imagebutton

Im new to android..please guide me..

I want to set image to act as button..

How to implement this in xml and in class file?

I now the code to set button in xml and class file like this..

> ```
>   <Button
>      android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
>      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>      android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
>      android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
>      android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
>      android:text="Next" />
> ```

```
     Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
```

I want practice.png this image want to act as button..I have put this image into drawables..

Now how to implement this by code...please guide me...

Thank a lot...

Comment: put as background: android:backgroud="@drawable/practice.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xml you can add:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

And in Activity:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  //Do your stuff here
            }
        });
```

Comment: It shows error   E/AndroidRuntime(1364): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.finalpractice/com.example.finalpractice.FrontActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake now it is ok.I have edited the line: ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image); please replace Button with ImageView.

Comment: See to this question and answer please guide me stackoverflow.com/questions/14766454/…

Answer (score 1):

In a xml file:-

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
 android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
 android:background="@drawable/practice"
 android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />
```

or

In a Activity :-

```
Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
              //Do your stuff here
        }
    });
```

Comment: See to this question and answer please guide me stackoverflow.com/questions/14766454/…

Comment: @God'sGrace im not able to open this link so plz provide me valide link for guide u

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageButton`. You can set an image to it using `android:src="@drawable/myImage"` and you can set `OnClickListener` to it.

For example :

```
<ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
 android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
 android:src="@drawable/next_btn_img" />

ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
```

Comment: It shows error   E/AndroidRuntime(1364): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.finalpractice/com.example.finalpractice.FrontActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView

Comment: you have to change your xml declaration and using the view in java code too. both must be `ImageButton`. post your new xml and the way you are using the view in java code.

Comment: Change your answer like this.  ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);     it works..

Comment: you can use ImageButton or ImageView doesn't matter . Both views have the ability to set image as source and have OnClickListener. But the thing you need is more ImageButton, ImageView is getting used to hold images.

Comment: See to this question and answer please guide me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766454/how-to-pass-the-value-into-php-from-android