# How to pass the value into php from android?

Tags: php, android, json, parameters

I'm facing problem with passing the value to the php script from android.

I want the `questionid` to pass into php script `url_get_ansurl` but I can't pass the value.

How to do this?  Please guide me.

Thanks a lot.

> ```
>     try {
>         int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>         if (success == 1) {
>             System.out.println("Success");
>             groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>             System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>              for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
>             JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>             String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
>             System.out.println("Checking ::"+question);
>             ques1.add(question);
>             String questionid = c.getString(TAG_QUESID);
>             System.out.println("Checking ::"+questionid);
>             id=questionid;
>             quesid.add(questionid);
>              }
>         } else {
>             showAlert();
>         }
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
>     }
>         List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>         params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qid", qid));
>         json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_ansurl, "GET", params1);
>         System.out.println("ques value got");
>         Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
>         System.out.println("question");
>         try {
>         int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>         System.out.println("Success");
>         if (success == 1) {
>             System.out.println("Success");
>             groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>             System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>              for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
>             JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>                 String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
>                 System.out.println("Checking ::"+answer);
>                 answ1.add(answer);
>              }
>         } else {
>             showAlert();
>         }
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
>     }
>     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>         pDialog.dismiss();
>      ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));
>         //  j=0;
>         TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>         txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));
> ```

Comment: which `questionid` u want to send in PHP file?

Comment: String questionid or quesid..but quesid is array..I want when first question displays that first questionid i want to send into php...

Comment: @dilix please guide me..How to do this?

Comment: @dilix please edit the question alone.. Don't give downvote...

Comment: if you known which question is selected by user then use question array index to get `questionid` from `quesid`

Comment: Edition because the questions is not well formatted and downvote because you haven't provide any info about errors you have etc. You only paste peace of code and want others to guess what exactly you can't do and make all the work. This site is to help figure out the reason of trouble but not the trouble itself in abstract peace of code. Provide more info - where is the error, paste stacktrace etc. BTW what type json var is?

Comment: @dilix its String..I don't  get any errors I want to implement this.. I want pass the questionid to the php file..

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K how to implement your idea..canu you give example and answer it below..please guide me.. im new..

Comment: @God'sGrace : you can use `SharedPreferences` to store `questionid` when user select question and retrieve it from questionid SharedPreferences when u want to send it to server instead of sending intent to same Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K please can you give example..i edit my full code above..please guide me..

Comment: @God'sGrace : just see [this example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html) for creating shared-preferences

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K i tried,it throws error, really i don't know were to add the sharedPreference..please guide me..in my code..

Comment: @God'sGrace : ok post followng part of code First: where user is selecting Question and second : where u want to post question id to sever

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K see my code in onPostExecute im displaying the question by using array.. and i want to pass the questionid above this line json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_ansurl, "GET", params1); in params.. please guide me..frnd

Answer (score 2):

You can use this by POST or GET

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("questionid", questionid));

    try {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        HttpClient httpClientpost = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        //HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url_request);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_request);

        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,
                HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);


        HttpResponse responsePOST = httpClientpost.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
        String getresponse = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); //Response from the server
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is mysql, `url_request` is the URL of your server you want to POST or GET

Comment: If i code like this.. it shows error in questionid tells that to create local variable for questionid..so im code like this       String questionid=null;

Comment: Just assign your value to `String questionid = SOME_ID_STRING_BLAH;`

Comment: Now also shows error.. it shows    SOME_ID_STRING_BLAH cannot be resolved to a variable..  and tells that to create constant variable..

Comment: Replace SOME_ID_STRING_BLAH with your question id. (`example: String questionid = 102312312;`)

Comment: I code like this String questionid=questionid;   Now it shows The local variable questionid may not have been initialized...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24168/discussion-between-ramyle-and-godsgrace)