# How to put and get the value in same activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to put and get the value in same activity.. Can we do this.. It is possible to do?

I wrote like this its possible in same activity...

> ```
>     try {
>     int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>     if (success == 1) {
>         System.out.println("Success");
>         groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>         System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>          for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
>         JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>         String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
>         System.out.println("Checking ::"+question);
>         ques1.add(question);
>         String questionid = c.getString(TAG_QUESID);
>         System.out.println("Checking ::"+questionid);
>         id=questionid;
>         quesid.add(questionid);
>          }
>     } else {
>         showAlert();
>     }
> } catch (JSONException e) {
>     System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
> }
>     List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("questionid", questionid)); // here i want to pass the questionid
>     json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_ansurl, "GET", params1);
>     System.out.println("ques value got");
>     Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
>     System.out.println("question");
>     try {
>     int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>     System.out.println("Success");
>     if (success == 1) {
>         System.out.println("Success");
>         groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>         System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>          for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
>         JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>             String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
>             System.out.println("Checking ::"+answer);
>             answ1.add(answer);
>          }
>     } else {
>         showAlert();
>     }
> } catch (JSONException e) {
>     System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
> }
> protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>     pDialog.dismiss();
>  ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));
>     //  j=0;
>     TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>     txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));
> ```

Comment: Then why your use intent bcz this task also achieve by static as well simple variable.

Comment: try to use share preferences that u can get and put value in same acitvity

Comment: i don't understand the question

Comment: @njzk2 I want to pass questionid value into url_get_ansurl, its php file..

Comment: still don't understand what your issue is. (except for unmatch brackets) and methods in the middle of nowhere)

Comment: @njzk2 see in my code i have String questionid, i want to pass this value to url_get_ansurl(php file). how to pass this value..

Comment: i don't understand, it seems that this is what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

i guess the  sharepreferences will resolve that

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("counter", counter);
    editor.commit();


    SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
```

Comment: please refer this link and answer there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766454/how-to-pass-the-value-into-php-from-android

Comment: I understand the answer but i don't know were to implement this code..please guide me...i replace my full code please guide me..